# Boolean value in a while loop statement instead of "while true do" doesn't work

Tags: ruby

I tried to create a loop using a variable set to be boolean value `true`. I was expecting the value to change to `false` if a user inputs `"exit"`, and the next iteration to not happen because the `while` statement `"isTrue == true"` is no longer `true`.

```
isTrue = true

while isTrue == true do
  input = gets
  if input == "exit" then    # exitと入力されたら
    isTrue = false           # プログラムを終了
  else
    puts "LOOPING..."
  end
end

puts "ENDING NOW"
```

But it doesn't seem to be working and just keeps looping. Why isn't my code working?

Comment: Okay so you are new but super!

Comment: If the user types "exit" and presses the enter key, `input` will equal `exit\n"`, so `input` will never equal `"exit"`. You need to write `input = gets.chomp`. [String#chomp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-chomp), er, chomps off the newline character `"\n"`.

Comment: You can add "p input" after "input = gets". You will be able to figure out the error yourself.

Comment: And since `p` returns its argument, you can wrap virtually any expression in `p(...)` to examine its value without changing your program's behavior, e.g. `p(input = gets)` or `input = p(gets)` or `if p(input) == "exit" then`. In many cases, you can even omit the parentheses and just prepend a `p`, i.e. `p input = gets`

Answer (score 2):

Use `gets.chomp` instead of `gets` to remove tailing "\n" and it will work. So you will not deal with "exit\n" coming from `gets`

Answer (score 0):

```
[1] pry(main)> input = gets
exit
=> "exit\n"
[2] pry(main)>
```

It's because `gets` input will contain a `\n` in it. You need dealing with it.

Like this:

```
[2] pry(main)> input.chomp
=> "exit"
```

Usually ppl write like this:

```
[3] pry(main)> input = gets.chomp
exit
=> "exit"
```

Answer (score 0):

`rstrip` will help you in this case.

Your input is actually not exactly "exit", since you press the return button.

The below code will work.

```
isTrue = true

  while isTrue == true do
    input = gets
    if input.rstrip == "exit" then    # exitと入力されたら
      isTrue = false           # プログラムを終了
    else
      puts "LOOPING..."
    end
  end

puts "ENDING NOW"
```

Refer - [Standard Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html#method-i-rstrip)

Answer (score 0):

Your program can be made more compact:

```
while gets.chomp != 'exit' do
  puts 'LOOPING...'
end

puts 'ENDING NOW'
```

This version of the program does exactly the same thing as yours, but is much smaller and faster.

Good luck in your Ruby learning!

Comment: There are other ways to end input beside of pressing "enter", so you might not always have a trailing `\n`.

Comment: @Stefan, thank you! This is a very important point. I edited the answer, now it contain only the proposal for a general simplification of the code.